# How to handle error in ajax's $get with anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to write an ajax function like this

```
$.get("./v1/user/"+username, function(response) {
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML=response.username;
});
```

and on failure, I want to change style property of some other element.

How do I write a .fail or similar function here to handle the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I write a .fail or similar function here to handle the error?

You can use jQuery [`deferred.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail) or at versions 3.0+ `.fail()` or [`.catch()`](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/)

```
$.get("./v1/user/"+username)
.then(function(response) {
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML=response.username;
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // do stuff
})
```